# How to implement _() method?

Tags: types, interface, go, overloading

I found an interface with a method called `_` in it. I tried implementing it, but it's not working:

```
package main
func main() {}

func ft(t T) { fi(t) }
func fi(I) {}

type I interface {
    _() int
}

type T struct {}

func (T) _() int { return 0 }
func (T) _(int) int { return 0 }
```

```
$ go run a.go 
./a.go:4: cannot use t (type T) as type I in function argument:
  T does not implement I (missing _ method)
```

I also tried adding the overloaded method `_(int)` but that's not working either:

```
package main
func main() {}

type I interface {
    _() int
    _(int) int
}

type T struct {}

func (T) _() int { return 0 }
func (T) _(int) int { return 0 }
```

```
$ go run a.go 
# command-line-arguments
./a.go:12: internal compiler error: sigcmp vs sortinter _ _
```

Why? What is the purpose of this `_` method? I think it might be a way to prevent people from implementing the interface (like private interfaces in Java)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`_` is the "blank identifier" (https://golang.org/ref/spec#Blank_identifier) and has special rules. Specifically:

> The blank identifier may be used like any other identifier in a declaration, but it does not introduce a binding and thus is not declared.

Also note that the section on Interfaces (https://golang.org/ref/spec#Interface_types) says:

> each method must have a unique non-blank name

So that interface isn't even valid go; the fact that the compiler apparently accepts it is a bug. Whichever package is declaring it really shouldn't be doing that.

Comment: I have filed a bug report based on my reading of the spec, it will be interesting to see what the developers say: https://code.google.com/p/go/issues/detail?id=8578

Comment: ... closed as "WorkingAsIntended"